# Merge github pull request branch into local branch

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to merge a github pull request branch into a local branch?

IE something like

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
git checkout -b work_in_progress
git merge https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/13107
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
```

then you switch to the new branch

```
[master] $ git checkout BRANCHNAME
```

then you can merge as it as you wish. This is thanks to GitHub help - https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/

Answer (score 0):

go to your local branch and do this. as you already on branch `work_in_progress`

```
git pull origin branch_name
```

If you haven't committed anything yet , you can run

```
git fetch
git checkout branch_name // on which you want to work on
```

If you do not have any branch other than master then what you have done,
i.e creating new branch after clone will have all the data.