# Spyder IDE inside Anaconda3 installation of opticspy-0.2.1 module error

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, importerror, python-wheel

After many times I've tried installing `opticspy` as what the instructions written on its documentation page, this pops up Command

```
"python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in

C:\Users\[PC Name]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-3xlemy6i\unwrap\ .
```

Also, when I downloaded the wheel file of the `opticspy`(`opticspy-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`) , it successfully installed (as what the anaconda prompt says), but when I tried to import it on `Spyder`, it says..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-824cab08504e>", line 1, in <module>
    import opticspy

  File "C:\Users\[PC Name]\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opticspy\__init__.py", line 12, in
<module>
    from . import aperture, interferometer_seidel,interferometer_zenike

  File "C:\Users\[PC Name]\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opticspy\aperture.py", line 3, in
<module>
    import diffraction as __diffraction__

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'diffraction'
```

Can someone help me? I really need this package for our Project Study. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eggs/source code at PyPI seems to be buggy. The code at Github repository seems to be better but lacks `setup.py`. A broken and abandoned package.

You can try to clone https://github.com/Sterncat/opticspy and put it into `site-packages/` directory manually. If you apply [PR 21](https://github.com/Sterncat/opticspy/pull/21) yourself you get missed `setup.py` so you can run `pip install .` or `python setup.py install`.

Comment: so you mean I should follow the changes on the codes as shown on the Files Changed tab?

Comment: You can [apply a pull request locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46313010/7976758).

Comment: can you please help me on what to type to apply all the changes on the <opticspy> . I was doing it manually, changing each and every code but it took me a lot of time to change everything. There are a lots of error regarding to what I'm going to use. thanks

Comment: The pull request was merged at Aug 2. You can now try installing directly from https://github.com/Sterncat/opticspy

Comment: And please don't forget to say "thanks": https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers